# How to save OSM file in XML using python in the same structure of the exported .osm file from OpenStreetMap website?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, openstreetmap, networkx

I am using python `osmnx` to deal with OpenStreetMap and I am trying to save a networkx map in an `.xml` file with the same structure of the exported one from the openstreetmap.org. Is it possible to save the map in same XML structure as downloaded from website?

I am using `osmnx` for path planning and I am trying to save the map that includes the path in `.xml` format for further operations using `ox.save_graphml()`, which saves the map but in a different structure than the exported map for the same area from the OSM website.

```
ox.save_graphml(subgraph2 , filename='/home/ahmad/catkin_ws/src/osmgraph.xml')
```

I expect the XML file to have the same structure as the one from the exported .osm file from OpenStreetMap. But the output XML has different structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.save_graphml), `save_graphml` saves your graph to disk as a GraphML file. The [GraphML file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML) is unrelated to the [OSM XML file format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). OSMnx can save your graph to disk as a shapefile or GraphML. It does not support saving to disk as an OSM XML file out of the box.

Comment: Yes I get it. I have managed to find another way to download the required OSM map directly from the https://overpass-api.de in using urllib library in python. Thank you for this very useful package.

Comment: How can I save the graph to Django static files?

Comment: I used this one https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.io `ox.io.load_graphml(url) ` `url = '.../static/xml/graph.graphml'`. When loading the graph with the saved graphml, but when I saved the graph it never added it to the url path, instead did the **data folder + graph.graphml**